# Png post data too large for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have canvas drawing app like scri.ch. My problem is, I send output from `canv.toDataURL('image/png')` as POST to PHP script. However, when I save these data to file, they get cut off. I thought that maybe it could be caused by low `max_input_vars` limit. I increased it to 1.000.000 and still nothing. JavaScript looks like this:

```
function toPng() {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<canvas id="copyCanvas" width="' + canv.width + '" height="' + canv.height + '"></canvas>';
    var copyCanv = document.getElementById('copyCanvas'),
    copyCtx = copyCanv.getContext('2d');
    copyCtx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    copyCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
    copyCtx.drawImage(canv, 0, 0);

    document.body.innerHTML += '<form id="imageData" method="post"><input type="text" maxlength="100000000" name="imageData" id="imageDataField"><input type="text" name="baseImage" id="baseImageField"></form>';
    var form = document.getElementById('imageData');
    form.action = './res/php.php';
    document.getElementById('imageDataField').value = copyCanv.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('baseImageField').value = window.location.search.replace('&img=', '') || '';

    form.submit();
}
```

When I echo sent data back, bottom part of image is missing. Any tips?

Comment: Try increasing the size of max_post_size in php.ini.

Comment: Also enable errors and listen to them carefully

Comment: As @JayBhatt pointed out, you need to increase the max_post_size as `canv.toDataURL()` converts to a base64 string which can be rather large depending on your canvas size

Comment: max_post_size = 10000000, still same

Comment: My canvas size: 1920x989

Comment: Does this occur x-browser?

Comment: Hmm, cool question. Actually, nope, it doesn't. In firefox, it works OK. In chrome, it gets cut. So, problem is probably on chrome side

Comment: Increase the max post size even more.  1920x989x4 = 7.5 meg. Double that to account for the base64 encoding and the result is potentially > than the 10 meg you have it set to if the image doesnt compress well.  Set it to something rediculously high to test, like 100M.

Comment: Also, you are setting maxlength to 10MB in the form markup as well. I would bump both php.ini and the form markup to 100MB as @GrandmasterB mentioned and report back

Comment: Data size is always capped at 524288 bytes

Comment: You also might want to use a hidden input instead of a text input for uploading in case the browser is doing something to the data.  Personally, I'd just use a jquery AJAX request, and pass the data to it without using a form element.  PHP has no problems whatsoever handling uploads of 10s or even 100s of megabytes. The problem is a setting or something you are doing on the client.

Comment: I, again, agree with @GrandmasterB here. Though I don't agree with using a monolith like jQuery to solve a simple problem. The XHR object is not tough to work with – especially if you don't need <IE9 which I'm guessing you don't since you are using Canvas API.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was that classical `<input>` has some interal maxlegth limit, which cannot be broken, because both textarea and POST ajax worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the size of your upload?  If it's reasonably small, you should check both your apache and PHP configuration files.

Comment: 524288 bytes from strlen, but actual size should be bigger

Comment: Did you check your apache configuration file?